# Prezados, como posso pegar o resultado do código abaixo e inserir numa tag HTML? Alguma forma de fazer utilizando handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocalização, ip, handlebars.js

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "freegeoip.app",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/json/",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Esse código parece ser de back-end, em node.js, não vejo como isso poderia ir no front-end, já que ele não é feito para isso, é importante você [edit] sua pergunta [evitando imagens para demonstrar códigos por uma série de ótimos motivos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).